# Закрытие меню по клику на его пункт

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть меню, которое при клике на *"Бургер"* отображается на весь экран. 
При нажатии на любой из разделов сайта пользователь отправляется к нужной секции.

Вопрос: нужно, чтобы при нажатии на *"Контакты"* пользователя направляло к секции контакты и меню закрывалось. Как это сделать?

```js
// Menu
$("#mobileMenu").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('icon-active');
 $('.navbar-menu').toggleClass('open');
});

// scroll to section
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 800);
    return false;
    });
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

header {
   height: 100vh;
}

section {
  margin-top: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}
nav.navbar {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 z-index: 3;
}

.navbar.blue {
 background-color: #00829f;
}

#mobileMenu {
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 left: 20px;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 2;
}

#mobileMenu span {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 height: 4px;
 width: 30px;
 background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
 border-radius: 8px;
 transition: all .3s linear;
}

#mobileMenu span:nth-child(1) {
 top: 12px;
}

#mobileMenu span:nth-child(2), 
#mobileMenu span:nth-child(3) {
 top: 20px;
}

#mobileMenu span:nth-child(4) {
 top: 28px;
}

.icon-active span:nth-child(1), 
.icon-active span:nth-child(4) {
 opacity: 0;
}

.icon-active span:nth-child(2) {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.icon-active span:nth-child(3) {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

ul.navbar-menu {
 opacity: 0;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 transition: all 1s ease;
 pointer-events: none;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #00829f;
 z-index: 1;
}

ul.navbar-menu.open {
 opacity: 1;
 padding-top: 14vh;
 pointer-events: all;
}

ul.navbar-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding-top: 5vh;
 color: rgb(255,255,255);
 font-weight: 500;
}

a.navbar-logo {
 float: right;
 width: 180px;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 5px 0;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<header> 
  <nav class="navbar">
      <div id="mobileMenu">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <ul class="navbar-menu">
        <a href="index.html" class="transition"><li>Главная</li></a>
        <a href="index.html#about"><li>О нас</li></a>
        <a href="#services"><li>Услуги</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Команда</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Запись на прием</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Портфолио</li></a>
        <a href="#contact"><li>Контакты</li></a>
      </ul>

      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-logo">
        LOGO
      </a>
 </nav>
</header>
  
  
<section id="contact">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur error, corporis molestias mollitia at vero ullam ratione dolorum labore tenetur voluptatum incidunt eaque quasi animi amet sit eius, quod enim.
</section>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Menu
$("#mobileMenu").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('icon-active');
 $('.navbar-menu').toggleClass('open');
});

// scroll to section
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 800);
    return false;
    });

// Link Close Menu
$("#link_close").click(function() {
 $('#mobileMenu').toggleClass('icon-active');
 $('.navbar-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

header {
   height: 100vh;
}

section {
  margin-top: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}
nav.navbar {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 z-index: 3;
}

.navbar.blue {
 background-color: #00829f;
}

#mobileMenu {
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 left: 20px;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 2;
}

#mobileMenu span {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 height: 4px;
 width: 30px;
 background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
 border-radius: 8px;
 transition: all .3s linear;
}

#mobileMenu span:nth-child(1) {
 top: 12px;
}

#mobileMenu span:nth-child(2), 
#mobileMenu span:nth-child(3) {
 top: 20px;
}

#mobileMenu span:nth-child(4) {
 top: 28px;
}

.icon-active span:nth-child(1), 
.icon-active span:nth-child(4) {
 opacity: 0;
}

.icon-active span:nth-child(2) {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.icon-active span:nth-child(3) {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

ul.navbar-menu {
 opacity: 0;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 transition: all 1s ease;
 pointer-events: none;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #00829f;
 z-index: 1;
}

ul.navbar-menu.open {
 opacity: 1;
 padding-top: 14vh;
 pointer-events: all;
}

ul.navbar-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding-top: 5vh;
 color: rgb(255,255,255);
 font-weight: 500;
}

a.navbar-logo {
 float: right;
 width: 180px;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 5px 0;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<header> 
  <nav class="navbar">
      <div id="mobileMenu">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <ul class="navbar-menu">
        <a href="index.html" class="transition"><li>Главная</li></a>
        <a href="index.html#about"><li>О нас</li></a>
        <a href="#services"><li>Услуги</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Команда</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Запись на прием</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Портфолио</li></a>
        <a id="link_close" href="#contact"><li>Контакты</li></a>
      </ul>

      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-logo">
        LOGO
      </a>
 </nav>
</header>
  
  
<section id="contact">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur error, corporis molestias mollitia at vero ullam ratione dolorum labore tenetur voluptatum incidunt eaque quasi animi amet sit eius, quod enim.
</section>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо большое!